# Сделать переключение Табов на checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, tab

Здравствуйте! Столкнлся с проблемой реализации переключения табов с 2 вкладками на checkbox, ну чтобы когда показывалась 1 вкладка, а когда пользователь нажимал на checkbox чтобы открывалась вторая вкладка и закрывалась первая. Пробовал делать подобным образом, но не работает((

```
<div class="tabs">
         <label class="checkbox">

          <span class="checkbox__left">НТВ+</span>
           <input type="checkbox">
           <span class="checkbox__item"></span>
           <span class="checkbox__right">Триколор ТВ</span>
         </label>


           <div class="tabs__box visible">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.</div>
           <div class="tabs__box">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами .</div>
         </div>
```

CSS(Sass)

```
input[type="checkbox"]
    display: none
    &:checked + .checkbox__item
        &::before
            left: 73px

.checkbox
    &__item
        width: 141px
        height: 36px
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56)
        border-radius: 15px
        background-color: #064fb2
        display: inline-block
        background-image: linear-gradient(86deg, #05a8a5 0%, rgba(5, 168, 165, 0) 100%)             
        position: relative
        display: inline-block
        vertical-align: middle
        margin-left: 16px
        transition: all 0.2s ease   
        &::before
            content: ''
            background-image: url(../img/checkbox.png)
            background-size: cover
            background-position: center
            position: absolute
            width: 70px
            height: 36px
            left: 0
            top: 50%
            transform: translateY(-50%)
            cursor: pointer
            transition: all 0.2s ease   
    &__left
        font-family: "OSB", sans-serif
        font-size: 24px
        line-height: em(22px)
        color: #cccccc
        display: inline-block
        vertical-align: middle
    &__right
        font-family: "OSB", sans-serif
        font-size: 24px
        line-height: em(22px)
        color: #0066cc  
        display: inline-block
        vertical-align: middle
        margin-left: 13px
```

JS

```
$(function() {
 $('.tabs').find('.tabs__box:not(.visible)').hide();
   $('..checkbox').delegate('.checkbox__item:not(.checkbox__item:checked)', 'click', function() {
     $(this).parents('.tabs').find('.tabs__box').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(450);
   })
 })
```

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: В чём у Вас отличие каких-то "табов" от вкладок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант по условиям задачи:

```js
tabFunc();

function tabFunc() {
  const $tabs = $('.tab');
  
  $tabs.each(function() {
    const $tab = $(this),
      $tabInput = $tab.find('.tab_input'),
      $tabItem = $tab.find('.tab_item');

    showTab($tabInput, $tabItem);
    $tabInput.on('change', function(){ showTab($tabInput, $tabItem); });
  });

  function showTab( $tabInput, $tabItem ) {
    const inputChecked = $tabInput.prop('checked');

    if(inputChecked) {
      $tabItem.eq(0).hide();
      $tabItem.eq(1).fadeIn(350);
    } else {
      $tabItem.eq(0).fadeIn(350);
      $tabItem.eq(1).hide();
    }

    // Хотя я бы лучше сделал так:
    // $tabItem.eq(0).toggleClass('visible', !inputChecked);
    // $tabItem.eq(1).toggleClass('visible', inputChecked);
    // И анимации стилями
  }
}
```

```css
.tab_input,
.tab_item {
  display: none;
}

.tab_buttons {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.tab_container {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tab_label {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab_item { padding: 5px; }
.tab_item:nth-child(1) { background-color: #5ad475; }
.tab_item:nth-child(2) { background-color: #7fb2e6; }

.tab_item.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
  <div class="tab_buttons">
    <label class="tab_label">
      <input type="checkbox" name="tab_input" class="tab_input">
      НТВ+
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab_container">
    <div class="tab_item">Tab #1</div>
    <div class="tab_item">Tab #2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <div class="tab_buttons">
    <label class="tab_label">
      <input type="checkbox" name="tab_input" class="tab_input">
      НТВ+
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab_container">
    <div class="tab_item">Tab #1</div>
    <div class="tab_item">Tab #2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Использовать надо не `checkbox`, а `radio`, при чем если нужно всего 2 таба - можно сделать и без js (тут на любителя, можно и под 100 табов сделать, но выглядеть будет странно):

```css
.tab_input,
.tab_item {
  display: none;
}

.tab_buttons {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.tab_container {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tab_label {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab_item { padding: 5px; }
.tab_item:nth-child(1) { background-color: #5ad475; }
.tab_item:nth-child(2) { background-color: #7fb2e6; }

.tab_input:nth-child(1):checked ~ .tab_container .tab_item:nth-child(1),
.tab_input:nth-child(2):checked ~ .tab_container .tab_item:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <input type="radio" name="tab_input" id="tab_input-1" class="tab_input" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="tab_input" id="tab_input-2" class="tab_input">
  <div class="tab_buttons">
    <label for="tab_input-1" class="tab_label">Tab #1</label>
    <label for="tab_input-2" class="tab_label">Tab #2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab_container">
    <div class="tab_item">Tab #1</div>
    <div class="tab_item">Tab #2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если интересует jQuery вариант (как по мне более приемлемый):

```js
const $tab = $('.tab'),
  $tabInput = $tab.find('.tab_input'),
  $tabItem = $tab.find('.tab_item');
  
showTab();
$tabInput.on('change', showTab);

function showTab() {
  $tabInput.each(function(i) {
    $tabItem.eq(i).toggleClass('show', $(this).prop('checked'));
  });
}
```

```css
.tab_input,
.tab_item {
  display: none;
}

.tab_buttons {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.tab_container {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tab_label {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab_item { padding: 5px; }
.tab_item:nth-child(1) { background-color: #5ad475; }
.tab_item:nth-child(2) { background-color: #7fb2e6; }

.tab_item.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
  <div class="tab_buttons">
    <label class="tab_label">
      <input type="radio" name="tab_input" class="tab_input" checked>
      Tab #1
    </label>
    <label class="tab_label">
      <input type="radio" name="tab_input" class="tab_input">
      Tab #2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab_container">
    <div class="tab_item">Tab #1</div>
    <div class="tab_item">Tab #2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Обычные табы я знаю и сам делать, мне надо сделать табы именно со связкой чекбокса

Comment: @LiEm, в чем смысл? Логика то radio button'a или на эти чекбоксы ещё что-то завязано?

Comment: посмотрите код что я выложил и вы поймете, просто так по дизайну задано там получается есть только одна кнопка и выглядит это как чекбокс а 2 иили более кнопок как при обычных табах нельзя делать

Comment: @LiEm, а, да, неправильно интерпретировал вопрос. Окей, сейчас напишемс

Comment: @LiEm, добавил вариант с чекбоксом, воспроизводить на вашем примере лень, ибо лень конвертировать sass в css.

Comment: "MedvedevDev огромное спасибо, ничего страшного сам сконвертирую

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65339/discussion-between-liem-and-medvedevdev).

Comment: зайдите пожалуйста в чат

Comment: прошу прощения что не заметил вашего сообщения в чате, очень вас сильно там жду!!!